# How to test CakeEmail is called from a model

Tags: cakephp, testing, phpunit

In CakePHP 2.1 I'm trying to test that the CakeEmail::to() method is called from my model test case with the correct "to" email (In this example: cat@gmail.com).

I want the following test to pass but I get:

```
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:to> when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.
```

Here's the code in the Model and the test case:

```
<?php

// Model/Job.php

App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class Job extends AppModel {

        public function emailCat() {
                $CakeEmail = new CakeEmail();
                $CakeEmail->to('cat@gmail.com');
                $CakeEmail->subject('hello!');
                $CakeEmail->emailFormat('text');
                $CakeEmail->config('default');
                $CakeEmail->send('hi');
        }

}

// Test/Model/JobTest.php

class JobTestCase extends CakeTestCase {

        public function setUp() {
                parent::setUp();
                $this->Job = ClassRegistry::init('Job');
        }      

        public function testEmailCat() {

                // I want to assert CakeEmail::to() is called with correct email
                $CakeEmail = $this->getMock('CakeEmail' , array('to'));
                $CakeEmail->expects($this->once())
                    ->method('to')
                    ->with($this->equalTo('cat@gmail.com'));            

                $result = $this->Job->emailCat();
        }

}
```

Comment: you are killing mvc, sending* emails in models

Comment: Feel free to expand on this comment - where in the rule book does it  say an email should be sent from a controller?

Comment: There's no problem with sending emails from models. Some models can use other models and have a broader scope, just as long as they're separate from the controller logic. They're called "domain models", and are pretty powerful if you know how to use them.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model

So don't worry, you're not destroying the universe by sending e-mail through a model. But perhaps you could invoke another class that does the e-mail sending, if that makes you feel better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're mocking a completely different class then the one that is actually used on the model. On your model function, you instantiate a brand new email class which will be mocked. Instead, you need to make sure that the `CakeEmail` object that the model uses is the one mocked.

```
class Job extends AppModel {

        public $CakeEmail = null;  

        public function emailCat() {
                if (!$CakeEmail) {
                        $this->CakeEmail = new CakeEmail();
                }
                $this->CakeEmail = new CakeEmail();
                $this->CakeEmail->to('cat@gmail.com');
                $this->CakeEmail->subject('hello!');
                $this->CakeEmail->emailFormat('text');
                $this->CakeEmail->config('default');
                $this->CakeEmail->send('hi');
        }

}
```

Then update your test case to set the mock object on your Job model.

```
class JobTestCase extends CakeTestCase {

        public function setUp() {
                parent::setUp();
                $this->Job = ClassRegistry::init('Job');
        }      

        public function testEmailCat() {

                // I want to assert CakeEmail::to() is called with correct email
                $CakeEmail = $this->getMock('CakeEmail' , array('to'));
                $CakeEmail->expects($this->once())
                    ->method('to')
                    ->with($this->equalTo('cat@gmail.com'));  
                // use mock object instead of creating a brand new one          
                $this->Job->CakeEmail = $CakeEmail;
                $result = $this->Job->emailCat();
        }

}
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks! Read up on Dependency injection too and will be re-factoring some bit's to make testing easier. Many Thanks!